# Class inside dict - Django template

Tags: python, django

Probably a simple question but I've searched for a while and haven't been able to find an answer for how to cycle through all of the items in my dictionary and call the class items inside of the template

I've tried using custom template tags, but the syntax doesn't seem to line up with what I'd like.

Here is my code:

```
data = [[OrderedDict([('token', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), ('devices', [['Christmas Lights', 'XXXXXXXXXX'], ['Gold Beedrom Lamp', 'XXXXXXXX']])])], [[['5', 'off', 124], ['6', 'off', 124], ['7', 'off', 100], ['8', 'off', 124]]]]

#Dictionary and Class assignment

class LightStatus:
      def __init__(self,id):
          self.id = id
          self.state = None
          self.bri = None
      def add_data(self,id,state,bri):
          self.id = id
          self.state = state
          self.bri = bri

AllLights = dict()
for i in data[1]:
    for light in i:
        id = light[0]
        state = light[1]
        bri = light[2]
        AllLights[id] = LightStatus(id)
        AllLights[id].add_data(id,state,bri)
```

What I'd like to have in template:

```
#What I want to do in the template      
for i in AllLights:
    print(AllLights[i].id)
    print(AllLights[i].state)
    print(AllLights[i].bri)
return render(request, 'file.html', 'lights': AllLights)

#What I've tried
{% for light in lights %}
    {% for i in light %}
       {{lights.light.id}} #light being the variable from above.                
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've also tried using a custom template tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def lights(LightDict, i):
    return LightDict[int(i)]
#template 
{{ AllLights|lights.forloop.counter0 }}
```

To summarize what I'd like to do. I'd like to pass the `AllLights` dict to my template and then cycle through all of the keys and call `id`,`state`, and `bri` for each key.

Update:

Someone asks what happens when I print(AllLights) before render:

```
{'5': <dashboard.views.LightStatus object at 0x106f016a0>, '6': <dashboard.views.LightStatus object at 0x106f01320>, '7': <dashboard.views.LightStatus object at 0x106f01ac8>, '8': <dashboard.views.LightStatus object at 0x106f014e0>}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the response.

Comment: OK. And if you `print(AllLights['5'])`, what do you get?

Comment: <dashboard.views.LightStatus object at 0x106ebd7b8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (correctly) using an ordered dict to maintain order, so assuming the order in that dict is the desired order you should be able to just iterate over your ordered dict's `values` in your template:

```
{% for light in all_lights.values %}
  {{ light.id }}
  {{ light.state }}
  {{ light.bri }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you look closer, ordered dict only applies to key 0 not key 1. This does answer my question. Adding `.values` in the for statement makes a huge difference. Is their django docs on this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? `allLights` is an ordered dict - do you have data that's not in it? The `{% for %}` block above is equivalent to your "what I want to do in the template" for loop.

Comment: OrderedDict only applies to the first key in `data` not the second.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for is the doc for the `for` tag, but the real difference (I think) is the `values()` method of dicts - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values